# Query ETF price data

Tags: r, api, quandl

I'm attempting to query ETF daily price data (SPY) from Quandl's API in R with the following command:

```
spy <- read.csv("https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/SPY.csv")
```

But I'm getting the following error message:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open connection
>
> In addition: Warning message:
>
> In file(file, "rt") :
>
> URL 'https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/SPY.csv': status was '404 Not Found'

The same command works fine with stocks such as AAPL, but not ETFs. Are ETF data not available or saved in another database?

Comment: They don't include ETFs in their free database. I was wondering the same thing. I imagine you're looking for a replacement for Yahoo?

Comment: Sure am. Any idea what happened on Yahoo!'s end?

Comment: One of the staff came out on a forum to say they're going to discontinue the API.

Comment: Pitty... Have you found a good replacement database?

Comment: There are a few premium ones on Quandl that offer data. Other than that I'm afraid not. Looking at Yahoo finance on the web, even there the data they do provide for adjusted close looks wrong. Maybe they're unwinding Yahoo Finance as a whole? Shame as for me it's the only good service they have.

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that too. In addition they've got large gaps in their data that weren't there before. Their data are now completely unusable even if you could get around their cookie crumb requirement. I'll drop you a line if I come across any good database.
Finance was indeed the only good thing they had left and the only reason I kept using Yahoo...

Answer (score 2):

I used webscraping (`rvest`) to query free stock websites for ETF prices. The following takes the WKN (or ISIN, I suppose) and returns the historical prices:

```r
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

get_prices <- function(wkn){
    # Download prices for WKN

    cat("Quoting", wkn, "\n")
    erg <- html_nodes(read_html(paste0("http://www.quotrix.de/fonds/wkn/", wkn,
                                       "/historische_kurse")), "table") %>% 
        map(html_table, fill=T) 

    if(length(erg) != 1) stop("Error with ", wkn, ": Expected 1 table, found ", length(erg))
    return(erg[[1]])
}

safe_get_prices <- safely(get_prices)
erg <- safe_get_prices("ETF126")
#> Quoting ETF126
str(erg)
#> List of 2
#>  $ result:'data.frame':  597 obs. of  6 variables:
#>   ..$ Datum    : chr [1:597] "17.04.2020" "16.04.2020" "15.04.2020" "14.04.2020" ...
#>   ..$ Eröffnung: chr [1:597] "34,73" "34,05" "35,16" "35,58" ...
#>   ..$ Tageshoch: chr [1:597] "34,73" "34,05" "35,16" "35,58" ...
#>   ..$ Tagestief: chr [1:597] "34,73" "34,05" "35,16" "35,58" ...
#>   ..$ Schluss  : chr [1:597] "34,73" "34,05" "35,16" "35,58" ...
#>   ..$ Stücke   : chr [1:597] "-" "-" "-" "-" ...
#>  $ error : NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>